# jquery jrac, how to set center point watching when load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I see in document have viewport_content_x, viewport_content_y but I set it seem to not effect. It alway show at position 0,0 . https://github.com/trepmag/jrac

Did I config wrong something?

And how to prevent error get wrong value (crop_x,crop_y, crop_width,...) when the drop_box is move out image

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the docs are wrong. The jrac settings expect 'viewport_content_left' & 'viewport_content_top' instead